# Single quotes around math?

Tags: math-mode, syntax

I am using the [syntax](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/syntax.pdf) package, and I want to define a grammar like:

```
Rule = Head -> Tail
```

but when I do this:

```
\begin{grammar}
<rule> ::=  <head> `$\rightarrow$' <tail>
```

I get an error saying that Missing $ was inserted.

How can I single-quote a math character?

Thanks

Comment: Ops sorry I'll update the question... This is within that syntax package it seems.

Comment: possibly `\hbox{'$\rightarrow$'}` (with a left quote on the left) but if that doesn't work please (always) edit your question to have a complete small document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backquote `` ` `` is a special character in the `grammar` environment. Precede it by `\string` if you want an opening quote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
<rule> ::=  <head> \string`$\rightarrow$' <tail>
\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I found that `lit{$\rightarrow$}` also works!